# jQuery: removeClass when the class is part of the condition

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I was just wondering if this is possible with jQuery:

```
if (jQuery(".the-title").is('.selected')) {
    jQuery('.the-copy').css('display', 'block');
    jQuery(".the-title").removeClass('.selected'); //is this possible?
}
```

Basically I want to know if I can remove the class that creates the condition inside the if statement. If not, any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't really any value in asking yes/no questions here, because nobody really learns anything from them; the better approach would be to put together some sample code, try it out, see if it works, and -- if not -- ask for some clarification on how to get it working (after first searching for similar questions and checking the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com))

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's perfectly fine to run this code, as condition is evaluated before the inside block runs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You're just evaluating if the element has the class, if it does you can then determine if you want to remove it or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

YES

```
if ($(".the-title").is('.selected')) {
   $('.the-copy').show(); //does display -> block without animation
   $(".the-title").removeClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: In your code I am only seeing change from `.css(display', 'block')` to `.show()`. But nothing related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can. Remember removeClass and addClass in jQuery doesn't need the dot. The correct (and simpler) code would be:

```
$('.the-title.selected')
    .removeClass('selected')
    .siblings('.the-copy').css('display', 'block');
```

This is assuming .the-copy is a sibling of .the-title. You can replace that with any other jquery dom traversing function

Comment: "*Remember removeClass and addClass in jQuery doesn't need the dot*" -- Yet you have it in your code...Also, how do you know that the targeted `.the-copy` elements are siblings of this? You can't assume that

Comment: You are correct, forgot to remove when I copied code. fixed! As for sibling, I dont know, but I am showing as example. As I mentioned in the actual answer, the OP should replace that with whatever traversal he needs.

Comment: I don't see that there's a need to modify the selector already specified in the question; it may not be 'possible' or reasonable to target these elements using a simple dom traversal technique, nor is that the focus of the question. In any case, [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean, not a jQuery object -- so you can't chain it like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. However, your syntax for `removeClass` is incorrect. It should not include the preceding period:

```
if($(".the-title").is('.selected')) 
{
    $('.the-copy').css('display', 'block');
    $(".the-title").removeClass('selected'); //is this possible?
}
```

Please see this jsFiddle for a demo > http://jsfiddle.net/QL7ds/1/